# WordPress: PHP: How to perform a nested sort within a category for the desired results

Tags: php, wordpress, function, sorting

There is a plugin that I am trying to adapt for my meta_tags for use with WordPress.
It is called Categories by Title by http://www.mikesmullin.com.

What I am trying to achieve is a nested sort. I have three meta_keys.  A selection-no, release-month, and release-year.  I would like to sort posts within their category by release-year (asc), release-month (asc), then selection-no (asc).  For example: 1955 10 selection-no-1, 1956 10 selection-no-2, 1956 10 selection-no-5, and so on.

I have modified the code, however, it only sorts by the last meta_key listed, by release-year.

Here is the code.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','sort_categories_by_title');

function sort_categories_by_title($x) {
if(is_category()) {
    $x->query_vars['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
    $x->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'selection-no';
    $x->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'release-month';
    $x->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'release-year';
    $x->query_vars['order'] = 'asc';
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: I have looked at the usort as suggested and cannot figure out how to apply.  Again, any additional help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you - all for looking.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). You supply a comparison function which can look inside each item and choose what to order by.

Comment: I am looking through it now.  I understand the concepts, but not yet identified the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, every time you do `$x->query_vars['meta_key']` you overwrite the previous value, so you're only adding the last meta_key as a selection option.

On top of that WordPress only supports pulling by a single meta_key/meta_value comparison. To get the more complex comparison that you're after you should be filtering on `posts_where_paged` to add in more comparisons and `posts_orderby` to construct the order by clause that you need. You'll need a basic knowledge of raw SQL query writing to accomplish this.

You might consider restructuring your data as well and putting the release-date in to a real date format and using typecasting to take the string format of the meta_value and cast it as a date field to then do proper date based sorting operations on it.

Comment: Thank you for your assessment of this code.  I will look into a SQL query.

If I understand the second part of the response as placing the release-date in the the regular month day of the WordPress fields and sort by date, however, wanted to maintain separate data.  Where a date of the post maybe January 10, 2010 and the article is of a release date of March 27, 1956.

I am not an expert, moreso a novice who can "hack at" the code to make it work at times.  Though it would be nice if the complete answer would appear here some day, it looks like I will have to try harder to accomplish this.

Comment: I don't think you'd need to move the release date in to the actual publish date of the post. You can still save that as postmeta, but save it in to a single field so that its easier to sort by. Look up typecasting in MySQL to see how you can sort a varchar field like a date field and not have to do the complex comparisons like you'd have to do with separate fields.

Comment: Shameless plug time - I did a short blog post on type casting in mysql a while back: http://top-frog.com/2009/08/10/type-casting-in-mysql-one-possible-application/